flutter local_notification sound stops on swiping down the notification tray
I am using flutter local_notification. In my case i an using custom sound for notification and i want it to ring until someone taps it. but the issue is when notification come and user just swipe down the notification trey from the top it stops ringing i want it to stop when its taps.
code should written as
showNotification(
      {required RemoteMessage message, required bool initializeNotification}) {
    if (initializeNotification) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    }

    final iosSettings = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
      defaultPresentAlert: true,
      defaultPresentSound: true,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
    );
    const androidSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/ic_notification");
    final settings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidSettings, iOS: iosSettings);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: selectNotification,
    );
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        channel.id, channel.name,
        importance: Importance.max,
        icon: '@drawable/ic_notification',
        sound: const RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification_sound"),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        priority: Priority.high,
        playSound: true,
        autoCancel: true,
        ongoing: true,
        audioAttributesUsage: AudioAttributesUsage.alarm,
        additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[5])
        //  initializeNotification ? : null,
        );

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    String? tittle = "";
    String? body = "";
    Object? notification;
    if (message.notification != null) {
      notification = message.notification;
      tittle = message.notification!.title;
      body = message.notification!.body;
    } else {
      notification = message.data;
      tittle = message.data["title"];
      body = message.data["body"];
    }
    if (notification != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode, tittle, body, platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: jsonEncode(message.data));
    }
    onMessageOpenApp();
  }

i have also used additionalflag
